# I Want to reload Current opened page on refresh but it loads last Loaded page on refresh in place of Current page in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

as there are multiple forms in website i opened different forms in new tab Example i first open formA then opened formB then opened fromC but when i go on tab of formA and refresh it by using F5 then it reloads me formC rather then Current from formA. Please Help me out in easiest way on Asp.net C#.

Comment: How are you "opening different forms"?  Then you mention tabs - how are these loaded.  Reload via F5 will load whatever's in the browser address bar.

Comment: I loaded multiple pages on new tabs by right clicking on multiple form links and open in new tabs

Comment: Ah, *browser* tabs, not html tabs.

Comment: but once load all forms as i mentioned when i refresh a selected or current page which i want and reloads it by f5 button it opens the last page which was opened.

Comment: Yes i wants to load the Current page session on reload but it loads last page session which was created.

Comment: there is an example as when we searched things on google we opened multiple links in new tab by right click on link.. but when we go to new tab which we opened and refresh it.. so it reloads the same page.. i also want this type of senario

Comment: Sounds like your web site is stateful, i.e. the page that is returned depends on more than what is in the address bar.  Could be cookie, session state, etc. that is causing this behavior.  You will have to post some code in order for us to help.

Comment: masterWizard_ChildForms_PainPoints.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url('" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/MenuIcons/childBgImage.png") + "'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;  width:100%;  font-size:11px; display:none;");

masterWizard_ChildForms_Risks.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url('" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/MenuIcons/childBgImage.png") + "'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%; width:100%;   font-size:11px; display:none;");

Comment: above one is for CS

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use anchor tag with target blank property. may be this help.

Comment: This will only open in a new (browser) tab if you click the link - if you shift-click or right-click-new-tab then it doesn't use the target property.

Comment: Also, it would be `_blank` not "blank"

Comment: my question is not this. i just want to reload the same current page on refreshed not the last page which was loads.